# Perl Open multiple files and write to a single file side by side

Tags: windows, perl, concatenation

I am running a Perl script in windows ,which creates multiple text files with some info. I would like some help with a Perl script to put all the text file data into one file side by side. I know I could use nested `foreach` loop to parse through each file and print them side by side. But the number of files varies.
For example:

Input:

`file1.txt`:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

`file2.txt`:

```
DDD
EEE
FFF
```

Output:

```
AAA  DDD
BBB  EEE
CCC  FFF
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The linux tool `paste` also provides this functionality, if you're not set on rolling-your-own perl script.

Answer (score 0):

What about :

```
open my $fh, ">", "concat.txt" or die $!;
my $string = qx(
    @echo off;
    type %*.txt;
);
print $fh $string;
```

?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::File;

my @files = (q[a.txt], q[b.txt]);

my @fhs = ();

foreach my $file (@files)
{
    my $fh = new IO::File $file, O_RDONLY;
    push @fhs, $fh if defined $fh;
}

while(1)
{
    my @lines = map { $_->getline } @fhs;

    last if grep { not defined $_ } @lines[0..(@fhs-1)];

    print join(qq[\t], map { s/[\r?\n]+/ /g; $_ } @lines) . qq[\r\n];
}

map { $_->close } @fhs;
```